# C ++ Use of undeclared identifier error when it has already been declared elsewhere

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a Binary Tree based on the code I have been given by my professor, but Xcode keeps telling me "root" is undefined in the binarySearchTree.h even though it has already be defined in binaryTree.h. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

This is the binarySearch tree file.

```
//Header File Binary Search Tree
#ifndef H_binaryTree
#define H_binaryTree

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    //Definition of the Node
template <class elemType>
struct nodeType
{
    elemType info;
    nodeType<elemType> *lLink;
    nodeType<elemType> *rLink;
};

    //Definition of the class
template <class elemType>
class binaryTreeType
{
public:
    const binaryTreeType<elemType>& operator=
                 (const binaryTreeType<elemType>&); 
      //Overload the assignment operator.

    bool isEmpty() const;
      //Function to determine whether the binary tree is empty.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the binary tree is empty;
      //               otherwise, returns false.

    void inorderTraversal() const;
      //Function to do an inorder traversal of the binary tree.
      //Postcondition: Nodes are printed in inorder sequence.

    void preorderTraversal() const;
      //Function to do a preorder traversal of the binary tree.
      //Postcondition: Nodes are printed in preorder sequence.

    void postorderTraversal() const;
      //Function to do a postorder traversal of the binary tree.
      //Postcondition: Nodes are printed in postorder sequence.

    int treeHeight() const;
      //Function to determine the height of a binary tree.
      //Postcondition: Returns the height of the binary tree.

    int treeNodeCount() const;
      //Function to determine the number of nodes in a 
      //binary tree.
      //Postcondition: Returns the number of nodes in the 
      //               binary tree.

    int treeLeavesCount() const;
      //Function to determine the number of leaves in a 
      //binary tree.
      //Postcondition: Returns the number of leaves in the 
      //               binary tree.

    void destroyTree();
      //Function to destroy the binary tree.
      //Postcondition: Memory space occupied by each node 
      //               is deallocated.
      //               root = NULL;

    virtual bool search(const elemType& searchItem) const = 0;
      //Function to determine if searchItem is in the binary 
      //tree.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is found in 
      //               the binary tree; otherwise, returns 
      //               false.

    virtual void insert(const elemType& insertItem) = 0;
      //Function to insert insertItem in the binary tree.
      //Postcondition: If there is no node in the binary tree
      //               that has the same info as insertItem, a
      //               node with the info insertItem is created
      //               and inserted in the binary search tree.

    virtual void deleteNode(const elemType& deleteItem) = 0;
      //Function to delete deleteItem from the binary tree 
      //Postcondition: If a node with the same info as 
      //               deleteItem is found, it is deleted from
      //               the binary tree.
      //               If the binary tree is empty or 
      //               deleteItem is not in the binary tree, 
      //               an appropriate message is printed.

    binaryTreeType(const binaryTreeType<elemType>& otherTree); 
      //Copy constructor

    binaryTreeType();   
      //Default constructor

    ~binaryTreeType();   
      //Destructor

protected:
    nodeType<elemType>  *root;

private:
    void copyTree(nodeType<elemType>* &copiedTreeRoot,
                  nodeType<elemType>* otherTreeRoot);
      //Makes a copy of the binary tree to which 
      //otherTreeRoot points. 
      //Postcondition: The pointer copiedTreeRoot points to
      //               the root of the copied binary tree.

    void destroy(nodeType<elemType>* &p);
      //Function to destroy the binary tree to which p points. 
      //Postcondition: Memory space occupied by each node, in 
      //               the binary tree to which p points, is 
      //               deallocated.
      //               p = NULL;

    void inorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const;
      //Function to do an inorder traversal of the binary
      //tree to which p points.  
      //Postcondition: Nodes of the binary tree, to which p
      //               points, are printed in inorder sequence.

    void preorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const;
      //Function to do a preorder traversal of the binary
      //tree to which p points.  
      //Postcondition: Nodes of the binary tree, to which p
      //               points, are printed in preorder 
      //               sequence.

    void postorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const;
      //Function to do a postorder traversal of the binary
      //tree to which p points.  
      //Postcondition: Nodes of the binary tree, to which p
      //               points, are printed in postorder 
      //               sequence.

    int height(nodeType<elemType> *p) const;
      //Function to determine the height of the binary tree
      //to which p points. 
      //Postcondition: Height of the binary tree to which 
      //               p points is returned.

    int max(int x, int y) const;
      //Function to determine the larger of x and y.
      //Postcondition: Returns the larger of x and y.

    int nodeCount(nodeType<elemType> *p) const;
      //Function to determine the number of nodes in 
      //the binary tree to which p points. 
      //Postcondition: The number of nodes in the binary 
      //               tree to which p points is returned.

    int leavesCount(nodeType<elemType> *p) const;
      //Function to determine the number of leaves in  
      //the binary tree to which p points 
      //Postcondition: The number of leaves in the binary 
      //               tree to which p points is returned.
};

    //Definition of member functions

template <class elemType>
binaryTreeType<elemType>::binaryTreeType()
{
    root = NULL;
}

template <class elemType>
bool binaryTreeType<elemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return (root == NULL);
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorderTraversal() const
{
    inorder(root);
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::preorderTraversal() const
{
    preorder(root);
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::postorderTraversal() const
{
    postorder(root);
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::treeHeight() const
{
    return height(root);
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::treeNodeCount() const
{
    return nodeCount(root);
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::treeLeavesCount() const
{
    return leavesCount(root);
}

template <class elemType>
void  binaryTreeType<elemType>::copyTree
                       (nodeType<elemType>* &copiedTreeRoot,
                        nodeType<elemType>* otherTreeRoot)
{
    if (otherTreeRoot == NULL)
        copiedTreeRoot = NULL;
    else
    {
        copiedTreeRoot = new nodeType<elemType>;
        copiedTreeRoot->info = otherTreeRoot->info;
        copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->lLink, otherTreeRoot->lLink);
        copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->rLink, otherTreeRoot->rLink);
    }
} //end copyTree

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorder
                              (nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        inorder(p->lLink);
        cout << p->info << " ";
        inorder(p->rLink);
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::preorder
                              (nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->info << " ";
        preorder(p->lLink);
        preorder(p->rLink);
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::postorder
                              (nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        postorder(p->lLink);
        postorder(p->rLink);
        cout << p->info << " ";
    }       
}

   //Overload the assignment operator
template <class elemType>
const binaryTreeType<elemType>& binaryTreeType<elemType>::
        operator=(const binaryTreeType<elemType>& otherTree)
{ 
    if (this != &otherTree) //avoid self-copy
    {
        if (root != NULL)   //if the binary tree is not empty,
                            //destroy the binary tree
            destroy(root);

        if (otherTree.root == NULL) //otherTree is empty
            root = NULL;
        else
            copyTree(root, otherTree.root);
    }//end else

    return *this; 
}

template <class elemType>
void  binaryTreeType<elemType>::destroy(nodeType<elemType>* &p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        destroy(p->lLink);
        destroy(p->rLink);
        delete p;
        p = NULL;
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void  binaryTreeType<elemType>::destroyTree()
{
    destroy(root);
}

    //copy constructor
template <class elemType>
binaryTreeType<elemType>::binaryTreeType
                (const binaryTreeType<elemType>& otherTree)
{
    if (otherTree.root == NULL) //otherTree is empty
        root = NULL;
    else
        copyTree(root, otherTree.root);
}

    //Destructor
template <class elemType>
binaryTreeType<elemType>::~binaryTreeType()
{
    destroy(root);
}

template<class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::height
                             (nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + max(height(p->lLink), height(p->rLink));
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::max(int x, int y) const
{
    if (x >= y)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::nodeCount(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    cout << "Write the definition of the function nodeCount."
         << endl;

    return 0;
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::leavesCount(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    cout << "Write the definition of the function leavesCount."
         << endl;

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

And here's the binarySearchTree.h file where I'm getting the errors about root being undefined.

```
//Header File Binary Search Tree

#ifndef H_binarySearchTree
#define H_binarySearchTree
#include <iostream>
#include "binaryTree.h"

using namespace std;

template <class elemType>
class bSearchTreeType: public binaryTreeType<elemType>
{
public:
    bool search(const elemType& searchItem) const;
      //Function to determine if searchItem is in the binary 
      //search tree.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is found in 
      //               the binary search tree; otherwise, 
      //               returns false.

    void insert(const elemType& insertItem);
      //Function to insert insertItem in the binary search tree.
      //Postcondition: If there is no node in the binary search
      //               tree that has the same info as 
      //               insertItem, a node with the info 
      //               insertItem is created and inserted in the
      //               binary search tree.

    void deleteNode(const elemType& deleteItem);
      //Function to delete deleteItem from the binary search tree 
      //Postcondition: If a node with the same info as deleteItem
      //               is found, it is deleted from the binary 
      //               search tree.
      //               If the binary tree is empty or deleteItem
      //               is not in the binary tree, an appropriate
      //               message is ptinted.

private:
    void deleteFromTree(nodeType<elemType>* &p);
      //Function to delete the node to which p points is 
      //deleted from the binary search tree.
      //Postcondition: The node to which p points is deleted
      //               from the binary search tree.
};


template <class elemType>
bool bSearchTreeType<elemType>::search
                    (const elemType& searchItem) const
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current;
    bool found = false;

    if (root == NULL)
        cout << "Cannot search an empty tree." << endl;
    else
    { 
       current = root;

       while (current != NULL && !found)
        {
            if (current->info == searchItem)
                found = true;
            else if (current->info > searchItem)
                current = current->lLink;
            else
                current = current->rLink;
        }//end while
    }//end else

    return found;
}//end search

template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::insert
                 (const elemType& insertItem)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
    nodeType<elemType> *newNode;  //pointer to create the node

    newNode = new nodeType<elemType>;
    newNode->info = insertItem;
    newNode->lLink = NULL;
    newNode->rLink = NULL;

    if (root == NULL)
        root = newNode;
    else
    {
        current = root;

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent = current;

            if (current->info == insertItem)
            {
                cout << "The item to be inserted is already ";
                cout << "in the tree -- duplicates are not "
                     << "allowed." << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if (current->info > insertItem)
                current = current->lLink;
            else
                current = current->rLink;
        }//end while

        if (trailCurrent->info > insertItem)
            trailCurrent->lLink = newNode;
        else
            trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;
    }
}//end insert

template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::deleteNode
                                (const elemType& deleteItem)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
    bool found = false;

    if (root == NULL)
        cout << "Cannot delete from an empty tree." 
             << endl;
    else
    {
        current = root;
        trailCurrent = root;

        while (current != NULL && !found)
        {
            if (current->info == deleteItem)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;

                if (current->info > deleteItem)
                    current = current->lLink;
                else
                    current = current->rLink;
            }
        }//end while

        if (current == NULL)
            cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the tree." 
                 << endl;
        else if (found)
        {
            if (current == root)
                deleteFromTree(root);
            else if (trailCurrent->info > deleteItem)
                deleteFromTree(trailCurrent->lLink);
            else
                deleteFromTree(trailCurrent->rLink);
        }
        else
            cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the tree."
                 << endl;
    }
} //end deleteNode

template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::deleteFromTree
                                 (nodeType<elemType>* &p)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent;  //pointer behind current
    nodeType<elemType> *temp;      //pointer to delete the node

    if (p == NULL)
        cout << "Error: The node to be deleted is NULL."
             << endl;
    else if (p->lLink == NULL && p->rLink == NULL)
    {
        temp = p;
        p = NULL;
        delete temp;
    }
    else if (p->lLink == NULL)
    {
        temp = p;
        p = temp->rLink;
        delete temp;
    }
    else if (p->rLink == NULL)
    {
        temp = p;
        p = temp->lLink;
        delete temp;
    }
    else
    {
        current = p->lLink;
        trailCurrent = NULL;

        while (current->rLink != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent = current;
            current = current->rLink;
        }//end while

        p->info = current->info;

        if (trailCurrent == NULL) //current did not move; 
                               //current == p->lLink; adjust p
            p->lLink = current->lLink;
        else
            trailCurrent->rLink = current->lLink;

        delete current;
    }//end else
} //end deleteFromTree

#endif
```

I will be extremely grateful if someone can tell me what is going wrong here.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: It reads, exactly, "Use of undeclared identifier 'root'".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Frequently Asked Question.

See the C++ FAQ item ["Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class? "](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html).

Quoting the FAQ:

> ”the compiler does not look in dependent base classes (like `B<T>`) when looking up nondependent names (like `f`).”

A **dependent base class** is a base class that depends on some template parameter. The compiler has no way of knowing that the base class hasn’t been or will not be specialized for whatever type or value the template parameter is. Thus the rule is that it can’t blindly assume that things exist, it must be *told* to assume.

The FAQ lists the following workarounds (with reference to the FAQ’s own example):

> •    Change the call from `f()` to `this->f()`. Since `this` is always implicitly dependent in a template, `this->f` is dependent and the lookup is therefore deferred until the template is actually instantiated, at which point all base classes are considered.
>
> •    Insert using `B<T>::f;` just prior to calling `f()`.
>
> •    Change the call from `f()` to `B<T>::f()`. Note however that this might not give you what you want if `f()` is virtual, since it inhibits the virtual dispatch mechanism.

In your case you’re referencing a data item instead of a function, but the same applies.

Comment: Avoiding stuff like this is why I always use ``this`` when referring to members/methods of classes. It takes a little longer, sure, but at least you're always very clear what you're referencing, both to yourself/other programmers and the compiler.

Comment: I think I understand what this says, but I'm not sure how to actually implement that in my code. What would I need to do here since it gives the error in so many different locations?

Comment: Just change all the ``root`` occurrences to ``this->root``

Comment: Wow. I can't believe this worked. Thank you so much. Amazing.